# MySQLdb on Cygwin

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Using MySQLdb on Cygwin and Python, I get the below error. I dont want to install MySQLDB on Cygwin. Is there a way that i can use the windows version of MySQL and just connect to it.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  2 2013, 22:34:09)
[GCC 4.8.1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root" )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket      '/var/run/mysql.sock' (9)")
```

I created the my.cnf file as below

```
$ cat /etc/my.cnf
[client]
 host            = 127.0.0.1
 port            = 3306
 socket          = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I also created the mysql.sock file as below.

```
$ pwd
/var/run/mysql

$ cat mysql.sock
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet=8M
```

I dont know what else is needed for this to run. Any ideas?

Comment: Experts - Any ideas on the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket should be created automatically by the MySQL server during startup, but it's not always in the folder that `MySQLdb` expects. You may find it at `/tmp/mysql.sock`, which is the [default value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket) of the `--socket` command line argument. If not, you can search for it with the following [bash command](http://ss64.com/bash/):

```
$ find / -name 'mysql.sock' 2>/dev/null
```

If `MySQLdb` by default looks for the socket at `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, but you find that your socket is somewhere else, you can use the `unix_socket` argument to the connection function, e.g.:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user=myuser, passwd=mypass, unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock')
```

The `host` and `port` arguments are optional, and normally when you want to connect through a unix socket you can omit them both, because you want the default host and you're not using a TCP port.

Comment: This Worked - db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="root" , unix_socket='/var/mysql/mysql.sock', port=3306 ). Just had to add the port too.

Comment: @myloginid 3306 is the default port; specifying `port=3306` has no effect on how the code is executed. The problem with [your last attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931459/mysqldb-on-cygwin/23962521?noredirect=1#comment36889592_23931990) was simply a typo - you tried to connect on port 3036. In this case, the `unix_socket` argument is also not doing anything because `host=127.0.0.1` tells MySQL to use TCP. So if that worked, then `db = MySQLdb.connect(host=127.0.0.1, user='root', passwd='root')` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found a complete solution but if you use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" it will work.  Not sure why yet but localhost works with curl from cygwin but not mysql or python.

Update: You don't need to define either the .cnf or .sock file

Comment: Hi, I got the same error. My DB is up for sure. I have double checked that. I tried the connect with the port specified too.

>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="root", port=3036 )
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (0)")